# Client outlook account deleted on client system, Need to recover e-mails that are on server back client's workstation

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

I have 2 client compters running XP and MS office with Outlook 2007.
I have a 2003 server running exchange.
Clients e-mail account was removed on clients computer.
But the e-mails are still on server as I see the mailbox with approx 14k of mail
How do I restore the e-mail account on clients and retrieve the e-mail from server.
I did not set up the outlook or exchange, so I do not know the e-mail settings.

Any help?

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new profile for the user for Outlook. You can do this in the Mail Control Panel in XP. Once the profile has been created to properly point at the Exchange mailbox, it should automatically see all of the data on the Exchange server. This isn't really a recovery - it's just a connection to a mailbox. Unless the user was using Outlook as a POP client, this is how it is supposed to work. However, you say that you don't know the email settings. That will be a bit of a challenge - you can't create a new profile without that stuff. You'll need 1) a username, 2) a password, 3) the name of the Exchange server.

Comment: The user should provide items 1 and 2. Item 3 can be obtained be checking the settings on the other client machine.